# Total noob here. Just installed 13.04 and it doesn't recognize my second monitor

Tags: 13.04, drivers, graphics, monitor

I click Detect Displays but it doesn't recognize my second monitor. I only see the main one. My graphics card is a geforce 9800 GT.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I also was unable to get output on my second monitor (HDMI). The system saw that a monitor was connected, but no output. I had to go to the System Settings, Software & Updates application, and on the tab farthest to the right, "Additional Drivers", it listed about seven different drivers for the NVidia card. I tried a couple before I found one that would run the second monitor. The one I am using now, which seems to work well, is the "NVIDIA binary Xorg driver,  kernel module and VDPAU library from nvidia-313-updates (propietary). Perhaps one of those will work for you too.